# How to set date as default value in Arcmap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I need to set default value of the field `"ExpireDate"` to `31/12/9999`. When I'm trying to set it it changes to the number `2958465`.

What is the problem here?

Comment: What is the type of the field?

Comment: Why not just leave it null?

Comment: What is the underlying DBMS?

Comment: Are you trying to do this via a [**feature template**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000001n000000)?

Comment: 2958465 is the serial day number for the last day of the year 9999.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, 2958465 is the number representation of 31/12/9999. It is likely that the field you're storing the date is an integer field.

To test this, I created a feature class in a file geodatabase with a Date field "DateExpire" and an integer field "DateExpireInt". I populated the date field with 31/12/9999. Then, I populated the integer field with the value of the DateExpireInt. The result is 2958465.

[image]

As a side note, this date relates to the [Y10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_10,000_problem).